# Kivy RecycleView for creating a table containing a lot of data. How to speed up the process?

Tags: python, kivy

I'm creating a scrollable table in python kivy using RecycleView. The table have to contain almost 1100 rows and 10 columns... RecycleView is doing lazy-loading... Realy too slow.

Somebody knows how to speed up the process? Maybe RecycleView is not appropriate?

thank you!

```
      BoxLayout:
            RecycleView:
                viewclass: 'background_example'
                data: [{'text': str(x)} for x in range(10000]
                RecycleGridLayout:
                    cols: 10
                    size_hint: 1, None
                    default_size: None, dp(20)
                    default_size_hint: 1, None
                    height: self.minimum_height
                    width: self.minimum_width
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Hello John, just posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two problems with your code:

1. You are creating that large list of 10000 items twice. Once in the `on_pre_enter()` method of `Screen_2` and again in the `kv` code for `Screen_2`
2. You are creating that large list on the main thread, which freezes your GUI.

To handle the first issue, you can change the `kv` for `Screen_2`:

```
<Screen_2>:
    BoxLayout:
        RecycleView:
            viewclass: 'Sfondo_tabella'
            # data: [{'text': str(x)} for x in root.data_items]
            data: root.data_items  # just reference the list instead of recreating it
            RecycleGridLayout:
                cols: 10
                size_hint: 1, None
                default_size: None, dp(20)
                default_size_hint: 1, None
                height: self.minimum_height
                width: self.minimum_width
```

To address the second issue, use a `Thread` to do the data creation in `Screen_2`:

```
class Screen_2(Screen):
    data_items = ListProperty([])

    def on_pre_enter(self, *args):
        # start the thread
        Thread(target=self.build_data).start()

    def build_data(self):
        x = 0
        # break the data build into 20 pieces
        for i in range(20):
            tmp_data = []
            for j in range(500):
                # create data entry for the current x and save it in tmp_data
                tmp_data.append({'text': str(x)})
                x += 1
            # add this block of data to the data_items on the main thread
            Clock.schedule_once(partial(self.load_data, tmp_data))

    def load_data(self, tmp_data, dt):
        self.data_items.extend(tmp_data)
```

Comment: Thanks John! I need some help to implement your solution in a real case.. Please, read below

Answer (score 0):

Here's a minimal reproducible example:

Until we have just 1.000 cells, the table is created in 2 or 3 seconds.

If instead of 1.000 I write 10.000 in the for loop, my pc need about 50 seconds to create the table composed by 10.000 cells.. it is not acceptable.

temp.py:

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty
from kivy.properties import ListProperty

class Sfondo_tabella(RecycleDataViewBehavior, Label):
    ''' Add selection support to the Button '''
    index = None
    selected = BooleanProperty(False)
    selectable = BooleanProperty(False)

class Screen_1(Screen):
    pass

class Screen_2(Screen):
    data_items = ListProperty([])
    def on_pre_enter(self, *args):
        for x in range(1000):
            self.data_items.append(x)

class TempApp(App):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TempApp().run()
```

temp.kv:

```
ScreenManager:
    id: screen_manager
    name: "screen_manager"

    Screen_1:
        id: screen_1
        name: "Screen_1"
        manager: screen_manager

    Screen_2:
        id: screen_2
        name: "Screen_2"
        manager: screen_manager

<Sfondo_tabella>:
    # Draw a background to indicate selection
    color: 0,0,0,1
    font_size:  self.height * 0.5
    text_size: self.width, None
    valign: 'top'
    halign: 'center'

    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (1, 1, 1, 1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba:0,0,0,1
        Line:
            width:0.5
            rectangle:(self.x,self.y,self.width,self.height)


<Screen_1>:
    Button:
        text: "Create table"
        on_press:
            root.manager.transition.direction = 'up'
            root.manager.current = 'Screen_2'

<Screen_2>:

    BoxLayout:
        RecycleView:
            viewclass: 'Sfondo_tabella'
            data: [{'text': str(x)} for x in root.data_items]
            RecycleGridLayout:
                cols: 10
                size_hint: 1, None
                default_size: None, dp(20)
                default_size_hint: 1, None
                height: self.minimum_height
                width: self.minimum_width
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your solution and works very well. thanks..

Just another question:

To implement your solution in a real case, if we have to import data from a table using postgres without knowing how many items I have to create, How to adapt the code?
(assuming the table has 1000 rows anch 10 columns)

I've only edited the 'build_data' function, getting a 10 times faster execution of code (from 50 sec to 5 sec), but it's still much slower then the code you posted (1,5 sec), I guess because I'm breaking the data build into 1000 pieces(rows), not 20...

```
    def build_data(self):
        self.data_items = ''

        stato_maschere = psycopg2.connect(dsn)
        cur = stato_maschere.cursor()

        cur.execute("SELECT col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4, col_5, col_6, col_7, col_8, col_9, col_10 "
                    "FROM table_1 "
                    "WHEREcol_1 != '' ")

        rows = cur.fetchall()

        for row in rows:
            tmp_data = []
            for x in row:
                tmp_data.append({'text': str(x)})
            Clock.schedule_once(partial(self.load_data, tmp_data))
```

Comment: I can't give you any exact recommendations, but I would suggest doing some experimentation. First, put in some `print` statements that print the time that your code takes in connecting to the db and fetching the query results, basically everything from the start of `build_data` up to the start of the `for` loop. That will give you the minimum time that you can shoot for.

Comment: Then, experiment with how often you are calling `load_data`. Right now you are calling it for every row, that'a one extreme. Calling just once for the entire data set is the other extreme. The best performance is likely somewhere in between. You can only figure that out by doing some testing.